# CloudFormation Template to accept parameter from external file

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-parameter-store

I am trying to achieve the same thing but for Parameter Store. My scenario is, Developers will provide a .json file with key/value. That file should be used by the CloudFormation template to create Parameter Store resources based on the entry made as a json file.

Main template -

```
    {
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Parameters": {
    "SSMParameterStore": {
        "Description": "SSM Parameter Store",
        "Type": "String"
    }
},
"Resources": {
        "InputParameters": {
            "Type": "AWS::SSM::Parameter",
            "Properties": {
                "Name": {"Ref": "ParameterKey"},
                "Type": "String",
                "Value": {"Ref": "ParameterValue"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Input Template -

```
[{
"ParameterKey": "KeyPairName",
"ParameterValue": "MyKey"
},
{
"ParameterKey": "InstanceType",
"ParameterValue": "m1.micro"
}
]
```

Command:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name test --template-body file:///home/user/Documents/Work/training/test/templt.json --parameters file:///home/user/Documents/Work/training/test/test.json --region us-east-1
```

Output:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Parameters: [SSMParameterStore] must have values
```

Not sure what is missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template has a parameter of `SSMParameterStore` but you are passing in `KeyPairName` and `InstanceType`.

Comment: Thanks, @Jason Wadsworth for the reply. Are You saying that I should have two parameters one for key and one for value And then refer them in the resources section? As - 
`{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Parameters": {
 "SSMParameterStore": {
  "Description": "SSM Parameter Store",
  "Type": "String"
 },
 "SSMParameterValue": {
  "Description": "ssm value",
  "Type": "String"
 }
}

And refer SSMParameterStore/Value to Name & Value place? Or it's wrong referencing.

Comment: What exactly is the goal here? It looks like you want to pass in a couple of values and have those values stored in parameter store. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, But the list is long and dynamic.

Comment: You're looking to do something that CloudFormation is not designed to do. For what you want to do you might consider using the CDK, or possibly using some CloudFormation Transforms.

Comment: Thanks, let me look at CloudFormation Transforms. btw, what is CDK?

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my own post with bit advancement.

Below is the working template.

Master Template -

```
    {
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Parameters": {
    "KeyPairName": {
        "Description": "ssm key",
        "Type": "String"
    },
    "KeyPairValue": {
        "Description": "Value",
        "Type": "String"
    },
    "KeyPairName1": {"Description": "ssm key", "Type": "String"},
    "KeyPairValue1": {"Description": "ssm key", "Type": "String"}
},

"Resources": {
        "InputParameters": {
            "Type": "AWS::SSM::Parameter",
            "Properties": {
                "Name": {"Ref": "KeyPairName"},
                "Type": "String",
                "Value": {"Ref": "KeyPairValue"}
            }
    },
        "InputParamters": {
        "Type": "AWS::SSM::Parameter",
        "Properties": {
            "Name": {"Ref": "KeyPairName1"},
            "Type": "String",
            "Value": {"Ref": "KeyPairValue1"}
        }
    }

}
}
```

Parameter Template -

```
    [
    {
        "ParameterKey": "KeyPairName",
        "ParameterValue": "/config/dev/ms/FIRST_NAME"
        },
        {
        "ParameterKey": "KeyPairValue",
        "ParameterValue": "MY_F_NAME"
        },
        {
        "ParameterKey": "KeyPairName1",
        "ParameterValue": "/config/dev/ms/LAST_NAME"
        },
        {
        "ParameterKey": "KeyPairValue1",
        "ParameterValue": "MY_L_NAME"
        }

]
```

But the problem is that I have to keep updating the master template manually every time when there is a new key/value in the parameter template file.
I still couldn't find a way to do this dynamically where irrespective of a number of entries in parameter file my template should take all key/value and create/update resources in Parameter Store. It seems that writing a Python or Bash wrapper may do this.

Comment: No. As Jason said, use the [CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/home.html) for such a scenario.